# Installing haml/sass through rubygems

Tags: rubygems, haml, sass

```
meder@dunross:~$ sudo gem install haml
Successfully installed haml-3.0.12
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for haml-3.0.12...
Installing RDoc documentation for haml-3.0.12...
Could not find main page README.rdoc
Could not find main page README.rdoc
Could not find main page README.rdoc
Could not find main page README.rdoc
meder@dunross:~$ haml
bash: haml: command not found
```

It seems like it installs haml then comes across something and doesn't install the full way. I have rubygems 1.3.6-2 and ruby 1.8.x. Debian Lenny OS.

Has anyone had this issue before or know what it could be?

Extra information:

```
meder@dunross:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

haml (3.0.12, 3.0.9)
maruku (0.6.0)
syntax (1.0.0)
yard (0.5.8)
meder@dunross:~$ gem list haml

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

haml (3.0.12, 3.0.9)
```

**Update #1:** I realized I installed 2 versions of haml, so I got rid of them both:

```
meder@dunross:~$ sudo gem uninstall haml

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. haml-3.0.9
 2. haml-3.0.12
 3. All versions
> 3
Successfully uninstalled haml-3.0.9
Successfully uninstalled haml-3.0.12
meder@dunross:~$ sudo gem install haml --development
Successfully installed haml-3.0.12
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for haml-3.0.12...
Building YARD (yri) index for haml-3.0.12...
Installing RDoc documentation for haml-3.0.12...
Could not find main page README.rdoc
Could not find main page README.rdoc
Could not find main page README.rdoc
Could not find main page README.rdoc
```

**Even more information**:

```
meder@dunross:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/meder/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
meder@dunross:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Might be a $PATH thing in that it isnt picking up the rubygems directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I appended my $PATH with `:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin` and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The "Could not find README" notices aren't errors. Haml doesn't use RDoc, but Rubygems doesn't have a good way of saying that, so it still looks for README.rdoc.